# Asp.Net trouble with links

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am new to web dev in ASP.NET, I seem am running into trouble with links. Here are a couple of questions:

I have this in my masterpage file:

```
<div class="title">            
                <a href="~/Default.aspx">Backyard Cures</a>
            </div>
```

When a user clicks on the title, I want him/her sent back to the home page. However, this doesn't seem to be working. Instead, when I am in the Login or registration pages it sends me back to the login page. When I am in default.aspx it sends me to /localhost/~/Default.aspx. Doesn't the ~ mean root?

I am also wondering how to make my urls more user-friendly. I don't want Default.aspx appearing for the home page etc.

Answer (score 2):

The anchor tag (`<a>`) is a standard HTML tag and tilde character (`~`) is specific to .NET

You should use `<asp:HyperLink runat="server"  NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Backyard Cures"></asp:HyperLink>` when utilizing the tilde character.

Also, if your Master Page or Content Page or a resource it uses is protected by authentication you will be redirected to login page.

For making links more readable you can use one or more options from below:

1. Friendly Urls package from nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Aspnet.FriendlyUrls/
2. Switch to MVC project instead of Web Forms project
3. Use custom routing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you. What about making the links prettier?

Comment: use `CssClass` property of HyperLink control to add a .css class to the link

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific: I want the displayed URL's to be more user-friendly. For example, when a user goes to Default.aspx, I want the URL to show sitename.com/home

Comment: ah. you can use Friendly Urls package from nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Aspnet.FriendlyUrls/, or switch to MVC instead of web forms. Or use custom routing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Do you mean the address bar or the top of the browser where the title is? If you set a title on the .aspx page, it'll be what gets rendered in the browser bar and the name of the bookmark as well when the user bookmarks the site.

Answer (score 1):

Change to HyperLink to run as a **Web Control:**

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/BusinessOrderInfo/page.aspx" Text="Whatever" runat="server" />
```

Or, run the anchor on the server side as an **HTML Control:**

```
<a href="~/BusinessOrderInfo/page.aspx" runat="server" >
```

Or, use **Page.ResolveUrl:**

```
<a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/BusinessOrderInfo/page.aspx") %>">...</a>
```

For making the url prettier

With web forms, the url is pointing to a file on your disk, with MVC is pointing to a controller action. If you're using webforms, you'd want to use URL rewriting. [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net) has a good article on doing URL rewriting.

Comment: Thank you. What about making the URL's prettier? How do I do that? For example, I want Default.aspx to show sitename.com/home in the browser.

Comment: Edited please check :)\